# Write a bat file to remove postfix from folder names

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a bat file to traverse a directory structure and remove the postfix " - Optimised Images" from folder names e.g. "folder_name - Optimised Images"

I've found a solution that does something similar to filenames but i've obviously not edited it correctly?:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR %%F IN ("* - Optimised Images") DO CALL :process "%%F"

:process
SET oldname=%1
SET "newname=%~nx1"
SET "newname=%newname:*] =%"
REN %oldname% "%newname%"
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
    for /d %%a in (* - Optimised Images) do (
    SET name=%%a
    call :Rename "%%~na"
    )

    Exit /b

    :Rename
    set "str1=%~1"
    set "str3=%str1: - Optimised Images=%"
    ren "%name%" "%str3%"
    )

    Exit /b
```

Answer (score 1):

This will remove it from folders

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /d %%a in (C:\folders\* - Optimised Images) do (
set name=%%~nxa
set newname=!name: - Optimised Images=!
ren "%%a" "!newname!"
)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response.  I have implemented your solution and have received the following error: "The syntax of the command is incorrect" Unfortunately I do not know enough about bat file syntax to fix myself :/

Comment: Try now, I think it must be the directory name it doesn't like, I didn't specify the whole path in the new name :)

Comment: `REN`'s second argument must be just a name, without a path. Also, it is always a good idea to enclose paths/names in double quotes.

Comment: @user2018320 See my updated answer, it works fine for me now :) Just remember to change the path to the folder that has all the folders you want to rename in it.